# What IDE do you recommend for Ruby on Rails on Windows with Cygwin?

Tags: windows, ruby, debugging, ide

I want to be able to use this IDE to step though code and debug.

So far I have found:

"e" Text Editor (http://www.e-texteditor.com/) $34.95
Arcadia (http://arcadia.rubyforge.org/)

Has anybody ever tried either of these and how are they?  Or anything else you can suggest?

Comment: But what about when using Cygwin?

So E is a no for debugging...

Answer (score 2):

If you're specifically looking for debugging capabilities, then the following fit the bill:

- [Ruby in Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Ruby-In-Steel-Developer-Overview)
- [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/)

While [E Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com) has no debugger as such, it's a great editor for working with Ruby and Rails due to its similarity to TextMate and compatibility with its Bundles.

Answer (score 1):

in windows, it's got to be aptana http://www.aptana.com/ - it has strong debugging capabilities although it is a bit of a process hog

Comment: make sure you install the RadRails addon and then read this guide on stepping through code http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Starting_a_Ruby_debug_session

Answer (score 1):

komodo ide from activestate has ruby and debugging; however, I won't be able to comment on the cygwin piece you asked about until next week when I actually set up cygwin on my windows box

Comment: I am very interested in how komodo works out for you.  Please let us know whether you liked it?  Thanks!

Comment: I went back to Eclipse because Komodo had a 5-26 second delay when alt-tab between windows. Apparently my mapped network drives (all 12 of them) create issues and some setting has to be disabled for alt-tab to function. ActiveState was very responsive and pointed me to Bug #79589; They also noticed a frustrated tweet and responded. I tried it because the best Java architect I know swears Komodo rules and uses it for everything!!  Apparently it's a great product. :)

Answer (score 0):

E.texteditor is very good one.

On linux I use gEdit (gMate with plugins)
On windows: E.Texteditor
On Mac: TextMate.

They have got many similar functionality (such as bundles and themes). I don't think that big IDE's are good solutions for rails development. So I recommend you to look at e.texteditor on windows.

Although you can look on vim or Emacs (I prefer Emacs) - they are hard on the beginning but very when you are experienced user - they give you many cool features. And they are platform independent. So you have got your editor everywhere you work.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider going down the Emacs route, the following link probably will be helpful:

http://nubyonrails.com/articles/emacs-emacs